# Oracle 11g connectivity issue with VBA

Tags: oracle11g, vba7

I am trying to connect Oracle with VBA using connection string OraOLEDB.Oracle and it is throwing an error `Provider not found`

- MS Office 365 - 64 bit
- Oracle 11g - 64 bit
- Windows7 - 64 bit

It is not possible for me to switch to 32 bit.

It will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the 64-bit OLEDB driver installed. Repair your Oracle installation or download it from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html).